# Do I require an airport Transit Visa at Frankfurt If I am travelling to United Kingdom?

Tags: uk, germany, transit-visas, layovers

I am  an Indian passport holder and will be flying from there.The flight I am looking at has 1 stop at Munich International Airport and has a 3h 55m layover there.I will need to switch flight there Do I require Germany airport transit visa to do that if I hold an UK D-tier 4 General entry clearance Visa?

Comment: Since UK is in transition period but EEA is still applied during this period I don't require Airport transit visa if I hold a valid visa of United kingdom?is this correct?                     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membership_of_the_United_Kingdom_in_the_European_Economic_Area

Comment: I am seeing different requirements at different sites https://www.germany.info/blob/917514/fffb0bebdc4dca0c6744cc066bc3b7ca/airport-transit-country-list-data.pdf https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/aamt/zugastimaa/buergerservice/faq/33-transit/606710

Comment: I am still confused since UK is no longer part of EU and EEA do the laws still apply during transition period?